# Spring Ignores @Transactional is not working

Tags: transactions, spring-data-jpa

Seems like spring ignores `@Transactional` annotations on service classes

If we manually create the tx bean its working fine

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { DatabaseConstants.SPRING_DATA_REPO_BASE_PACKAGE }, entityManagerFactoryRef = DatabaseConstants.SPRING_DATA_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY)
public class DatabaseConfig {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(Configuration dataBaseConfig) throws Exception {
        AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSource = new ShardSourceRouter();
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= CCMConfigUtil.getTotalShards(); i++) {
            targetDataSources.put(ShardDatabase.getShardDatabase(i), createDataSource(i, dataBaseConfig));
        }
        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(targetDataSources.get(ShardDatabase.SHARD_ONE));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private DataSource createDataSource(int shardNum, Configuration dataBaseConfig) throws Exception {
        JSONObject shardsConfig = new JSONObject(dataBaseConfig.getString(DatabaseConstants.SHARDS_CONFIG));
        JSONObject shard = shardsConfig.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(shardNum));
        DataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = (DataSourceFactory) dataSourceFactoryLocatorBean().getObject();
        FMSDataSource fmsDataSource = dataSourceFactory.getFMSDataSource(shard
                .getString(DatabaseConstants.DATASOURCE_POOL));
        return fmsDataSource.createDataSource(shard.getJSONObject(DatabaseConstants.PROPERTIES), dataBaseConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean fmsEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = null;
        try {
            Configuration dataBaseConfig = CCMConfigUtil.getDataBaseConfig(System
                    .getProperty(DatabaseConstants.APPLICATION_NAME));
            em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            em.setDataSource(dataSource(dataBaseConfig));
            em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { DatabaseConstants.SPRING_DATA_ENTITIES_BASE_PACKAGE });
            em.setPersistenceUnitName(DatabaseConstants.PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
            em.setJpaPropertyMap(getJPAProperties(new JSONObject(dataBaseConfig
                    .getString(DatabaseConstants.JPA_PROPERTIES))));
            em.afterPropertiesSet();
            LOG.info("Initialized EntityManagerFactory for PersistenceUnitName {}",
                    DatabaseConstants.PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception while initialize the EntityManagerFactory {}", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to initialize the EntityManagerFactory", e);
        }
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = fmsEntityManagerFactory();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
        transactionManager.setDataSource(entityManagerFactory.getDataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}

@Service
public class FulfillmentRequestManager {

    @Autowired
    private RequestFulfillmentService requestFulfillmentService;

    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    public Long createFulfillmentRequest(String buId, String martId, FulfillmentRequest fulfillmentRequest)
            throws Exception {

        requestFulfillmentService.save(fulfillmentRequestDO, shard);

    }
}

@Service
public class RequestFulfillmentService {

    @Autowired
    private FulfillmentRequestRepository fulfillmentRequestRepository;

    public FulfillmentRequestDO save(FulfillmentRequestDO fulfillmentRequestDO, long shard) {
        FulfillmentRequestDO fulfillmentRequestDOSaved = null;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        ShardContext.setCurrentShard(ShardDatabase.getShardDatabase(shard));
        fulfillmentRequestDOSaved = fulfillmentRequestRepository.save(fulfillmentRequestDO);
        LOGGER.info(SplunkLog.getDBLatency(className, "save", DBAction.FetchLatency.name(),
                stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
        ShardContext.clear();
        return fulfillmentRequestDOSaved;
    }
}

@Repository
public interface FulfillmentRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<FulfillmentRequestDO, Long> {

}
```

I feel some issue with the package of the class where I used the `@Transactional`.

Is there any specific config need to be added to identify the classes which can only use transactional annotations.

or is there any issue with the way I have defined the database config.

If we manually create the tx bean and autowired in the class its working properly

Comment: Can you expand on *@Transactional is not working*. How does this 'not working' manifest itself?

Answer (score 0):

Used @Transaction annotation on the method m2() called from another method m1() from same class. Where the m1() will be invoked from outside.

As m2() is not invoked from outside spring proxy is by passed.